# How do I get the current location on the Android Studio map activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-studio-electric-eel

I am creating an app, and it has a bottom navigation bar. One of the pages I am going to use for a map with the current location. The following shows my code so far for that page. Can this code be changed so that when entering the page, the current location is received first ?

This is the code in the MapsFragment.java file.

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public MapsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static MapsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MapsFragment fragment = new MapsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Initialize view
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

        // Initialize map fragment
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment=(SupportMapFragment)
                getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);

        // Async map
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                // When map is loaded
                googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                        // When clicked on map
                        // Initialize marker options
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions=new MarkerOptions();
                        // Set position of marker
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);
                        // Set title of marker
                        markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude+" : "+latLng.longitude);
                        // Remove all marker
                        googleMap.clear();
                        // Animating to zoom the marker
                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,10));
                        // Add marker on map
                        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use [fusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient). Or check this [documentation guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location).